# what is the difference between put and upload_project in fabric?

Tags: python, fabric

What is the difference between put and upload_project?
Do they have any benefits in speed?

```
put(local_tar, remote_dir)
upload_project(local_tar, remote_dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

Upload_project use the 'tar' and 'gzip' programs/libraries, while put use sftp program.

Put has also more options to use like 'mode'.